# Swedish characters in URL

Tags: asp.net, lucene, urlencode

I am currently having a problem in one of my projects. I have a search field which, once the user types in the value and press Enter, he is redirect to an url with the search term.

After that our ActionMethod `Search` will call our Lucene instance in order to return the results.
Let's say: http://site.se/search/också

I don't think that URL Encoding would work since we tried the encoded URL manually and the website crashed in the same way.
Like this: http://site.se/search/ocks%C3%A5

Is there any way to make the characters work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I've decided to make it simple, although it's not the best for my case.

http://site.se/search?q=också

Working like a charm now :-)